# How to detect auto responders

Tags: php, email, header

I have written a php e-mail processing client that uses the IMAP protocol.

I noticed that it processes auto responders like normal e-mails which is undesirable.  Is there something in the mail header that would indicate that the e-mail is not from a human but from an auto/vacation responder?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same problem happening for me. Could you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 100% reliable way to do this. However, automated messages *should* have an empty (`<>`) Envelope-From header (that's the RFC821 "MAIL FROM" header, not the RFC822 "From:" header).

How you determine what the Envelope-From header is from the messages you retrieve via IMAP will depend on your mail server implementation.